# Artgris FileManagerBundle change name of uploaded file

Tags: event-listener, symfony-4.4

Im using Symfony 4.4 with
[Artgris FileManagerBundle](https://github.com/artgris/FileManagerBundle)

Is there any possibility to change name of uploaded file?
I try Event Listener with events "file_manager.pre_update", "file_manager.post_update" but no success.
Nothing found in config but maybe there is some solution?
Want to change like sluggify
"Fav logo śćąóź∆.png" => "fav-logo-scaoz.png"